# change event on updated model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a list of fields

```js
fields: [  
  {
    id:0,
    label: 'dropdown 1',
    value: 0,
    options: [{ id: 0, value: 0, label: 'Option 1' }]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'dropdown 2',
    value: 0,
    options: [
      { id: 0, value: 0, label: 'Hide dropdown 1' },
      { id: 1, value: 1, label: 'Show dropdown 1' }
    ]
  }
]
```

that are filtered before being shown like so:

```html
<div v-for="field in fields.filter(ffield => showField(ffield))" :key="field.id">
  <b-form-select v-model="field.value" @change="changed(field)">
    <option v-for="option in field.options" :key="option.id" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </b-form-select>
</div>
```

I can hide 'dropdown 1' based on the selected option in 'dropdown 2'. This is managed by the 'showField' function:

```js
function showField(field) {
  return field.value !== 'dropdown 1' || fields[1].value === 1
}
```

Lets say `dropdown 1` is hidden and I select the second option `Show dropdown 1`. Vue's reactivity runs the `showField` function for all items in the list before running the `changed` event on the affected field. So now `dropdown 1` is visible and then the eventhandler is called.
But what's really weird is that the parameter `field` in the `changed` function corresponds to the value of fields[0] even though I selected an option in 'dropdown 2' or fields[1].
What is going on?

I understand that this doesn't happen when `dropdown 1` is after `dropdown 2` in the list.

I tried modifying `node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/form-select/form-select.js` rendering function but this must be some internal thing that's causing it and I'm not familiar enough to keep digging.
Maybe I disregarded some pattern for this sort of thing?
The filter in the v-for came in because we used v-if="showField(field)" together with the v-for and that was incorrect.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Did you try watch ?

Comment: do you have a `:key` for the outer v-for? without it, things go weird for sure

Comment: I have not used `watch` variables for this and I did use `:key`, I optimized that out, there's a unique id in each field object that I removed, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Alex Does the question still exist when you added `:key`?

Comment: @BigLiao yes, the key was always in there, I removed it for clarity in the example. I am trying to create a jsfiddle but it seems to be working fine there so I will keep trying to figure out my issue and report back when I can reproduce it in a short example.